# Assign object values conditionally JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, null

I am receiving a data object from an api where some of its properties may have a value of null. I want to create a function that returns the object but for the properties that have a null value there is a "-" instead. I have tried:

```
const hyphenOrContent = movie => {
    return Object.values(movie).map(val => {
        return val === null ? "-" : val
    });
}
```

but this only returns an array of the values. I've read that it's better not to use a for in loop so I would like to avoid using one if possible. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that, eg, `{ foo: 1, bar: null }` should turn into `{ foo: 1, bar: '-' }`?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the object's entries, turning `null`s into `-`s, then use `Object.fromEntries` to turn the array of entries into an object:

```
const hyphenOrContent = movie => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(movie).map(
        ([key, val]) => ([key, val === null ? "-" : val])
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the Object and alter the properties.

```js
const hyphenOrContent = movie => {
  Object.entries(movie).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (val === null) movie[key] = '-';
  });
};


var a = {
 foo: null,
 bar: '123',
 baz: null
}

hyphenOrContent(a);

console.log(a);
```

If you do not want to alter the original, you can clone it.